# NLog - RabbitMQ Cluster Target

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, nlog, elastic-stack

We are using NLog in our .Net application to feed logs to ELK.

The data flow is as below,

NLog -> RabbitMQ -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch -> Kibana

We have created RabbitMQ cluster(3 nodes with highly available queues) and unsure on how to configure Nlog to work with clustered RabbitMQ.

Comment: Is your question how to set-up "NLog -> RabbitMQ" in NLog?

Comment: Yes, NLog -> Clustered RabbitMQ in NLog.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NLog.RabbitMQ](https://github.com/haf/NLog.RabbitMQ),
although it is missing good documentation how to set-up. Check on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.RabbitMQ)